# unable to print all the elements shown in mobile view scrolling

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

How to print all the elements shown over the mobile screen in appium with java, actually i have written a code as:-

```
List<WebElement> orderidList=driver.findElementsByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@resource-id,'view_shipments_OrderNo_TextView')]")
for (int i = 0; i < orderidList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(orderidList.get(i).getText());
            }
```

But it prints name of orderids that are visible to mobile phone view. But i want distinct list of all the orderids, all orderids are visible after scrolling, i can implement the scrolling but i don't know how much i need to scroll. Please suggest!!
here is the screenshot of UI automator and i want to get list of all the orderids:-[image]

Comment: That simply means your xpath is incorrect. Post screenshot of uiautomatorviewer so we can build a valid xpath for you

Comment: @Shubham Jain:- added image above, pls help!!

Answer (score 1):

**This is expected behavior**. UiAutomator can detect only the visible elements on Android device's screen. You can get the list of elements are visible. If you want to get the list of all the elements then you need to scroll and get the list, scroll and get the list and so on till the ends. There is not way to get the list of in-visible elements for Android using Appium Inspector/ UiAutomator

Comment: :- can you please provide the dummy for this,

Answer (score 0):

Like Vinod already told it will only print visible elements on the screen. So you need to make your code do the steps we would do if we were to scroll manually, scroll until you dont see any new elements. Have a look at the code below. I have used linked hashset to maintain order of elements and not capture any duplicates.

```
Set<String> appList = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

By by = By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@resource-id,'view_shipments_OrderNo_TextView')]");

        String currentOrder, newOrder;

        do {

            currentOrder = driver.findElements(by).get(0).getText();

            int count = driver.findElements(by).size();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String appName = driver.findElements(by).get(i).getText();
                appList.add(appName);
            }
            driver.swipe(400, 400, 400, 74, 2000);

            newOrder = driver.findElements(by).get(0).getText();
        } while (!currentOrder.equals(newOrder));
```